# External image is not displayed when given with expression

Tags: image, reporting-services, expression, external

I have a report which reads the image names from database. (around 30.000 pictures a month i download with a python application and store them on a folder on the same server my report is running and store the names on database.)

so i added a table with image name as text and image object with MIMEType=image/jpeg, Source=External.
Query works perfect and brings the picture names but images are not shown. 
I have added several columns with image objects to find a way to make it work. So tried the value as

It only works on option 1) on design, preview or when i deploy the report.  non of 2) or 3) works.

1)file://C:/Python37/DataFiles_Picture/ML-20180104-EC0319_Infra_B14_IMG_4181.JPG

2)="file://C:/Python37/DataFiles_Picture/ML-20180104-EC0319_Infra_B14_IMG_4181.JPG"

3)="file://C:/Python37/DataFiles_Picture/"&Fields!picture_name.Value

i need the image from the expression. i desperately need your helps since i tried this about 7 hours now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by changing the permissions in the folder.